# Bulk create clean user_nicename from user_email with SQL function

Tags: users, mysql

All user_nicenames were replaced with a domain name in botched import. I'm trying to recreate them from the user_email filed but need them cleaned of all special characters ("@" and ".").

For example, this email from the user_email column:

> d.boone@wild.frontier

should be copied to the user_nicename column as:

> d-boone-wild-frontier

Is this something that can be done in bulk with a MySQL query/function? I have 5,000 users to fix.

Comment: You could do this with a simple WP-CLI script, but if you want to do it with SQL, your question is off-topic in this stack.